# Twitter Bootstrap css issue with "pull-left" class in Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I add ***class="pull-left"*** to an element it works fine in all browsers except Firefox where the width of the block element doesn't seem to be respected and squished up to the left. How can I fix this issue?

The only fix I've found so far is to use a pixel width on the < p > element but I want this element to resize as needed so that's not an option.

Link to site: http://julianjosephs.com/versature/bootstrap/

[image: pull left bug]

Code

```
<div class="testimonial-detail">
    <div class="media pull-left">
        <a href="#" class="pull-left">
            <span class="media-object">
                <img width="60" height="60" alt="Alison Drury" src="assets/images/testimonial.png">
            </span>
        </a>
            <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="media-heading">Alison Drury</h5>
            <p>Spring Health Leisure Clubs</p>
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="testimonial-right-quote pull-right"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: I am using FF version 22.0 | Chrome - latest version

Comment: you can try to add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.pull-left` class. but this probably will require setting `overflow: x;` to `.media, .media-body`

Answer (score 1):

shot in the dark but i've had good luck with this:

```
<div class="testimonial-detail">
    <div class="media pull-left">
         <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="media-heading">Alison Drury</h5>
            <p>Spring Health Leisure Clubs</p>
         </div>

        <a href="#" class="pull-left">
            <span class="media-object">
                <img width="60" height="60" alt="Alison Drury" src="assets/images/testimonial.png">
            </span>
        </a>

    </div>

    <div class="testimonial-right-quote pull-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `media-left` instead of `pull-left`